# Pyramid, Dart, setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, dart, pyramid, setuptools, dart2js

I'm starting to develop a web application in python 3 in the Pyramid framework and I would really like to use Dart instead of js. However, dart must be compiled to js in order to run in all browsers.

My question: what is a good workflow for developing a pyramid web app using dart? Should I develop the Dart code completely separate and just copy the built product into my Pyramid project? Or should I have it all in one right form the start and somehow manage it inside the package? Pyramid (more or less) forces the usage of setuptools/distutils and I relly don't know how should I deal with compiling the dart code in the setuptools/distutils context.

Or is there a completely differend workflow which didn't come to my mind?

I am right at the start and I am very open to possibilites.

Thanks for any answers/advice/whatever helps me.

---

Note: I'm using PyCharm IDE professional (i.e. with pyramid support) so a solution which works well in PyCharm is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger a compilation of Dart resources you could use "Before launch" tasks of every PyCharm  Run/Debug configuration as shown in a screenshot of a tutorial. There you would call `pub build` and build into an output directory that is picked up by your pyramid application.

- [Using PyCharm with Pyramid](http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pycharm/#install-development-and-documentation-requirements)
- [Dart pub commands](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/index.html)

Another handy feature during development is reloading. Pyramid has an option for reloading chameleon/jinja/mako templates. It think Dart Tools provide same feature to developers.

Good luck with your project. Just try if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a typical workflow for any "compiled" language (CoffeScript, Less, browserify etc.) is that you either run a command in console each time you make a change, which compiles your fancy language to JS/CSS, or you have something running in a console which watches a directory for any file changes and compiles them as soon as it notices a change.

So, basically, you would have, say, a `dart\` directory within your project and a `js\` directory. The magic console command would compile everything from the `dart\` directory and place the result into the `js\` directory. Then you would register a static view in Pyramid

```
config.add_static_view(name='js', path='my_package:a/b/c/js')
```

and reference the compiled js file from your template:

```
request.static_url('my_package:js/my_compiled_javascript.js')
```